# "wp i18n make-pot" can't generate translatable text

Tags: php, wordpress, internationalization, translation, wp-cli

ISSUE:
At theme folter, I'd tried running following commands:

1. wp i18n make-pot . languages/text-domain-locale.pot
2. wp i18n make-pot . languages/text-domain-locale.pot --slug=text-domain
3. wp i18n make-pot . languages/text-domain-locale.pot --domain=text-domain

None of them work with these code in theme:

1. __( 'source text', TEXT_DOMAIN );
2. _e( 'source text', TEXT_DOMAIN );

SOLUTION:
Code must be like the following, Wordpress is also has more functions like these:

1. __( 'source text', 'text-domain' );
2. _e( 'source text', 'text-domain' );

Then the command:

- wp i18n make-pot . languages/text-domain-locale.pot --domain=text-domain

Next, you can just rename .pot into .po and put in wp-content/languages/theme/text-domain-locale.po

We need to translate all items in the file then compile into .mo file:

- wp i18n make-mo wp-content/languages/theme/text-domain-locale.po wp-content/languages/theme/text-domain-locale.mo

At this time, your theme can switch to the target language for translated text.

I hope lost soul will find a way out earlier! Don't overnight like me :)!

Note: use get_locale() in theme to get current language locale code.

Comment: thanks for writing the solution here :)